# Get the key names of the object with value equals to something

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a better way to get the key names of the object with value equals to `cat`?

```
import { toPairs } from 'lodash'

const options = {
  x: 'cont',
  y: undefined,
  color: 'cat',
  radius: 'cat'
}

const catNames = toPairs(options).map(([name, type]) => type === 'cat' ? name : null).filter(n => n)
// [ 'color', 'radius' ]
```

Comment: `Object.keys(options).filter(k => options[k] === 'cat')`

Comment: @Ali Right, which is what's asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6+ in one line

```
let key = Object.keys(obj).find(k=> obj[k] === value);
```

Get all the keys with

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj).filter( k => obj[k] === value);
```